# The order of script execution in grails

Tags: grails

I am asking this question for the second time ( It was closed as being to broad) but I cant find any relevant info. Even putting a link on the comment box could help.

I want to know the order grails runs these scripts:
`BuildConfig` `Config` `Bootstrap` `DataSource`

***update:***
what I want is a write a script for environment aliasing.
For e.g if I run this `grails -Dgrails.env=qa3Env run-app` and I dont have this env so with in my code ( which I dont know where to put it) I have a logic that says if env is qa3Env create few config variables then apply the config of Environment qa2. In short after adding the few config variables I am aliasing qa2 and qa3. But to do this I dont know where to put my logic. With in  `BuildConfig` ,`Bootstrap` ..  ?

Thanks,

Comment: You might want to expand on your question and explain what problem you are having and trying to solve by understanding the order. As far as "order" is concerned, it's a difficult question to answer because  Bootstrap is the only ones that gets "run" the others are evaluated, which is slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is place a break point on each of this files :) . Place a break point at every line may be try to

```
println "first is something"
```

My justificatuion is the order of exection will be as follows :

```
1.Config 
2.BuildConfig 
3.Bootstrap 
4.DataSource
```

**Config** will be loaded since, even something on build config or the rest of the project needs to initialize there. Then the **buildConfig** that is second becuse , in order to run you application the server stuff, database, libraries to compile ..are there and environment setting too. **Bootstrap** will load the application then it will check you every other setting like **datasource** at least it exist and try to use you connection string their so. that's it !

Comment: That's not entirely correct. For instance, the **datasource** is parsed as a part of starting up the application, which is required before **bootstrap(s)** get executed. Your "println" test is fooling you into thinking the wrong thing is happening.

Comment: man ... there is no magic everything is executed one another whether its executed parallel or not. in my premises i have left a space to the chance of overlapping data source file before bootstrap ..